# Magento XML product feed with images and description

Tags: xml, magento, import

I'm looking for a solution for my magento store. 
I wanna sell IT products, I have my supplier, who has an XML service. But it needs to send requests, and I get a response.

And I have no idea how to solve this.

I want to update the catalogue, images, prices, descriptions etc. via XML.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea.

XML code looks like this:

```html
3.1.2 Response 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?> 
<Envelope> 
<Body> 
<Response> 
<Header> 
<Control> 
<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode> 
<ReturnText></ReturnText> 
</Control> 
</Header> 
<Body> 
<ProductId>NP300E5C-S04HU</ProductId> 
<PartNumber>NP300E5C-S04HU</PartNumber> 
<Name>NP300E5C-S04HU...</Name> 
<Description>Intel® Pentium® Processor B970...</Description> 
<Manufacturer> 
<ManufacturerId>A113</ManufacturerId> 
<ManufacturerName>Samsung</ManufacturerName> 
</Manufacturer> 
<FirstLevelCategory> 
<FirstLevelCategoryId>B011</FirstLevelCategoryId> 
<FirstLevelCategoryName>Notebook</FirstLevelCategoryName> 
</FirstLevelCategory> 
<SecondLevelCategory> 
<SecondLevelCategoryId>C223</SecondLevelCategoryId> 
<SecondLevelCategoryName>15col</SecondLevelCategoryName> 
</SecondLevelCategory> 
<ThirdLevelCategory> 
<ThirdLevelCategoryId>D397</ThirdLevelCategoryId> 
<ThirdLevelCategoryName>Intel Dual Core</ThirdLevelCategoryName> 
</ThirdLevelCategory> 
<Garanty> 
<GarantyMode>Szervizben</GarantyMode> 
<GarantyTime>1 + 1 év</GarantyTime> 
</Garanty> 
<Price>336,35 EUR</Price> 
<New>false</New> 
<Discount>false</Discount> 
<Stock> 
<StockInfo>Rendelhető</StockInfo> 
<HasStock>false</HasStock> 
<Value>0</Value> 
</Stock> 
<AdvertisementId></AdvertisementId> 
<AdvertisementShortDescription></AdvertisementShortDescription> 
<Available>true</Available> 
<Comparable>false</Comparable> 
<Currency>EUR</Currency> 
<DataAreaId>BSC</DataAreaId> 
<EndOfSales>false</EndOfSales> 
<IsInCart>false</IsInCart> 
<IsInNewsletter>false</IsInNewsletter> 
<IsInStock>false</IsInStock> 
<PictureId>6694</PictureId> 
<ProductFlag1>false</ProductFlag1> 
<ProductFlag2>false</ProductFlag2> 
<PurchaseInProgress>false</PurchaseInProgress> 
<ShippingInfo>Rendelhető</ShippingInfo> 
<StockInfo>Rendelhető</StockInfo> 
<Pictures> 12 

<Picture> 
<Id>6694</Id> 
<FileName>NP300E5C-S04HU.jpg</FileName> 
<Primary>true</Primary> 
<RecId>5637248599</RecId> 
<Content>[Base64 coded content of the picture]</Content> 
</Picture> 
</Pictures> 
</Body> 
</Response> 
</Body> 
</Envelope>
```

```html
3.1.1 Request 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Envelope> 
<Body> 
<Request> 
<Base> 
<AuthCode>##########-##########-##########-##########</AuthCode> 
<Language>hu</Language> 
<Currency>EUR</Currency> 
</Base> 
<ProductId>NP300E5C-S04HU</ProductId> 
</Request> 
</Body> 
</Envelope>
```

Comment: You haven't explained clearly what it is you need to do.

Comment: I have the products in the store. I need to update the products with their product photo and description. And the photos and description comes from the supplier via XML, but first I need to send a post request via XML to get a response via XML. But I have to send the requests one by one.

Comment: That's what you should say in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use API requests using cURL for this.

```
$url = '$client_url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And you can parse the $result xml like

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
```

Comment: Ehh... I think I'm not smart enough for this :(

Comment: Is this the answer you need?

Comment: By this method, I need to pull the info of each product one by one, and I need a complete XML file, that contains all products data in one file.

Comment: I think I should use this with magento dataflow  feature somehow, but I think I sould send a request with dataflow, and use the response with dataflow... But I have no idea how.

Answer (score -1):

I also get this php from the supplier, but no idea how to use it.

```html
 <?php
$url = 'http://www.xxxxxx.hu/CompanyGroup.XmlGateway/CatalogueService/GetCatalogueItem/';
$xml = '<Envelope>
           <Body>
            <Request>
             <Base>
              <AuthCode>########-########-########-########</AuthCode>
              <Language>hu</Language>
              <Currency>HUF</Currency>
             </Base>
             <ProductId>SMT750I</ProductId>
            </Request>
           </Body>
         </Envelope>';
$content_type = 'application/xml';
$options = array(
                                'http'      => array(
                                'method'    => 'POST',
                                'header'    => 'Content-type: ' . addslashes($content_type) .'\r\n'
                                              .'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml) . '\r\n',
                                'content' => $xml,
                            ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo ($result);
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please post this as a new question and delete this answer.